# Cannot call web service

Tags: java, connection, cxf, webservice-client

I am currently trying to call a web service with a client built with Apache CXF. Though the service is available in the browser, I cannot connect to it, due to the following error.

Any thoughts regarding the problem ?

```
org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doIntercept
INFO: Interceptor has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Connection refused: connect
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:75)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.BareOutInterceptor.handleMessage(BareOutInterceptor.java:68)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:276)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:222)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
        at $Proxy78.getStandardVersion(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.jsp.services.Result_jsp._jspService(Result_jsp.java:622)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:843)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:679)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1293)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Connection refused: connect
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:313)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:73)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:525)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:158)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:233)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:323)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:860)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:801)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:726)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:904)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1766)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1734)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:42)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:96)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:214)
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:311)
        ... 27 more
```

Answer (score 5):

Seems like one of two options

1. You are trying to connect to the wrong uri (server / port / url)
2. You trying to connect to a service which is blocked by a firewall

Maybee you could give us some more insight in the configuration you are using

Comment: the webservice is deployed on a Tomcat on my dev machine and the wsdl is available via a web browser.

Comment: I was more interested in how you implememted apache CXF so that I can help you more. If it is not one of the above options it is probably something in you CXF configuration

Comment: it looks like the problem is wsdl-related, i.e. the provided wsdl is invalid due to this ... "<wsdl:import location="http://localhost:8080/test/services/MyService?wsdl" namespace="urn:test:wsdl"></wsdl:import>"

Answer (score 2):

With CXF you can override the target url of the WSDL by the following CXF spring configuration

```
    <bean id="service" class="your.pack.age.YourService"
    factory-bean="clientFactory" factory-method="create">
</bean>

<bean id="clientFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceClass" value="your.pack.age.YourService" />
    <property name="address" value="${service.url}" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the browser settings, for sure you will find web proxy enabled, you need to pass the same settings in your code:

```
 HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
    http.getClient().setProxyServer("proxy server URL");
    http.getClient().setProxyServerPort(port);
```