# What is so special about the 2.2.8-SNAPSHOT version of cxf-codegen-plugin?

Tags: java, spring, jax-ws, cxf

I inherited a CXF based project, with the following (relevant) *original* dependencies (in `pom.xml`):

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

And

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

By "original" I mean that this is the source code snapshot I received that used to build fine **years ago**, has been dormant for all these years and now, that some modifications to the code are needed, it will *no longer build as is*.

The main problem with trying to build it "as is", is that the `2.2.8-SNAPSHOT` version of `cxf-codegen-plugin` is **nowhere to be found**... Maven can't find it and fails the build.

So, I replaced the above with (note that the only differences is 2.2.8 vs. 2.2.8-SNAPSHOT)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8</version>
```

The build succeeds now past this point but fails on 2 symbols not found:

1. `Password.set_value(String value)` -- from the package `org.oasis_open.docs.wss._2004._01.oasis_200401_wss_wssecurity_secext_1_0`.
2. `SQLService.setENDPOINT(String sei)` from own package based on `javax.xml.ws.Service`.

Both source files for the classes `Password` and `SQLService` are generated on-the-fly by Apache CXF 2.2.8, as designed by the original author of this project.

So, I quickly examined the new generated versions of this files and discovered that:

1. `Password.set_value(String value)` seems to have been substituted by `Password.setValue(String value)`.
2. `SQLService.setENDPOINT(String sei)` has been eliminated completely, and instead requiring that sei be passed in the constructor: `SQLService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName)`

So I modified the source code that calls these methods to adapt to this 2 seemingly minor changes and the project now builds successfully!

**But...** it fails at runtime with the following exceptions:

```
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://rservice.rorg.net/sql}SQLService#{http://rservice.rorg.net/sql}Get has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:487)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:313)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:265)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:124)
    at $Proxy38.get(Unknown Source)
        ...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: ConnectException invoking http://localhost:8080/rservice/services/SQLServiceSoap: Connection refused
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:522)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:2058)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:2043)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:66)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:639)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:413)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:274)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:261)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:556)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:403)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:521)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:246)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:320)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:337)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:948)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:873)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1040)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1955)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1907)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:42)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1974)
    ... 17 more


04-Jan-2013 12:07:17 ERROR [SQLModule] Error running SQL module: Could not send Message.
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
    at $Proxy38.get(Unknown Source)
    at net.rorg.rservice.client.base.sql.SQLClientBase.get(SQLClientBase.java:306)
    at net.rorg.rservice.client.module.sql.SQLModule.getBatch(SQLModule.java:149)
    at net.rorg.rservice.client.module.sql.SQLModule.getAndProcessSQL(SQLModule.java:110)
    at net.rorg.rservice.client.module.sql.SQLModule.run(SQLModule.java:280)
    at net.rorg.rservice.client.RClient.exec(RClient.java:398)
    at net.rorg.rservice.client.RClient.run(RClient.java:173)
    at net.rorg.rservice.client.RClient.main(RClient.java:166)
Caused by: 
java.net.ConnectException: ConnectException invoking http://localhost:8080/rservice/services/SQLServiceSoap: Connection refused
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:522)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:2058)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:2043)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:66)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:639)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:487)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:313)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:265)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:124)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:413)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:274)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:261)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:556)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:403)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:521)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:246)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:320)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:337)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:948)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:873)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1040)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1955)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1907)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:42)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1974)
    ... 17 more
```

**Note:** Even if I hardcode the actual (www) server URL in the WSDL (i.e. replacing `http://localhost:8080` with `https://test.rserver.com`), I get the *ConnectException* error displaying `http://localhost:8080` as the destination. Clearly, some CXF-substitution or resolution is not performed. Could that be a clue to where the problem is? Which component of CXF is responsible for that magical transformation from `http://localhost:8080` to the real URL?

Is it right where the stack trace hints (i.e. **JaxWsClientProxy** or **frontend.ClientProxy** or...)?

```
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:243)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:484)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:310)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:262)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:124)
```

If so, why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Now... if I were a CXF and/or JAX-WS expert, I would have probably figured out the root cause of that misleading "Connection refused" hint in the stack trace.

But at this point I am pretty much lost, since I know beyond certainty that the SEI is there, the authentication username/password are correct: The older binary (JAR with dependencies) runs just fine against this service.

I am therefore looking for a clue or an insight from an expert who may have seen this type of *"Connection refused"* stack trace and knows that it could be trigger by **other than** the [typical reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5260319/1864054). For example, some type of mismatch that has been introduced once the `cxf-codegen-plugin` 2.2.8-SNAPSHOT was replaced by 2.2.8?

Or additional tips on how to troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your change to `SQLService` might be the problem

> SQLService.setENDPOINT(String sei) has been eliminated completely, and
>   instead requiring that sei be passed in the constructor:
>   SQLService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName)

Did you put a new URL in the constructor call? What was `sei` before? If you've put in a URL, it's probably that whose connection is failing. You should be able to use the no-arg constructor.

If you want to set the URL at runtime (I guess that's what the `setENDPOINT` call was doing) you need to manipulate the `BindingProvider`. See this thread http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/How-to-change-the-service-URL-at-runtime-td3242927.html

Comment: Answering your question: Yes, of course I put the new URL in the constructor call: prior to the constructor statement, I a create a QNAME object: `final QName SERVICE = new QName("http://rservice.rorg.net/sql", "SQLService");`. Also, the original code doesn't really manipulate the URL at runtime, as it calls `setENDPOINT` immediately after the constructor statement. Additional insights? Thanks (+1).

Comment: @Daniel It's not so much 'at runtime' as 'not at compile time' - if you have a WSDL that has a placeholder endpoint location, you *need* to set the destination URL 'at runtime'. Is this the case for you? (I.E. does your WSDL have the correct location in it?)

Comment: Yes, of course the WSDL has the correct location in it (it hasn't changed BTW since the original build years ago). What I meant by *"doesn't really manipulate the URL at runtime"* was that of course the SEI is set at runtime by both the old & the new code, but this is done immediately after the constructor, not at some point down the code depending on later information to be retrieved. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. So does the no-arg constructor version of `SQLService` work? (Does it exist?)

Comment: Yes, a no-arg constructor version of SQLService exists. CXF actually generates 3 constructors: **1.** `SQLService()`, **2.** `SQLService(URL wsdlLocation)`, **3.** `SQLService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName)`. I initially tested with the 1-arg version and it didn't work. I never tried the no-arg version because I don't understand how something like this could even work... (doesn't it need both the WSDL location *and* the SEI?)

Comment: If you use the no-arg one, it uses the WSDL location from disk when you generated the classes. What is the actual, real, WSDL location for the application in deployment? It's not `http://localhost:8080/rservice/services/SQLServiceSoap` (from your stack trace), I presume?

Comment: The actual URL string in the WSDL is `http://localhost:8080/rservices/services/SQLServiceSoap` which is magically substituted at runtime (I still don't know how CXF does that) to run on any machine, be it test or production. **Or is it really?** See, I am still new to this and the fellow teammate that was instructing me about this, just said that the `localhost:8080` is what's supposed to be there. As for the actual WWW location, I am not at liberty to disclose this for employer confidentiality reasons. I will try the no-args to see if that makes any difference. Thanks so much.

Comment: I tried the no-arg version and it fails due the fact that the default constructor is using wsdlLocation that equals to `file:/C:/Users/daniel/workspace/rservice-client/src/main/wsdl/SQLServiceSoap.ws‌​dl` (actual WSDL source file in workspace). Looks like both paramters need to be explicitly provided at construction time. Also, see the update to my OP. I believe the **mapping/translation/conversion** between `http://localhost:8080` to the real www server URL is **the key**.

Comment: The 'mapping/translation/conversion' is the `provider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, target);` call in the link I provided. Why does your co-worker think `http://localhost:8080/rservices/services/SQLServiceSoap` is the correct WSDL location? I also don't understand why the default constructor call fails. Does that WSDL source file *not* exist in your workspace?

Comment: Some progress: The WSDL in the workspace is supposed to be overridden at runtime by values loaded from a config.xml file. But it doesn't. And the reason is that CXF 2.2.8-SNAPSOT produces a `wsdlLocation` equals to `"classpath:/net/rorg/rservice/sql/SQLServiceSoap.wsdl"` while CXF 2.2.8 produces `file:/C:/Users/daniel/workspace/rservice-client/src/main/wsdl/SQLServiceSoap.ws‌​‌​dl`. The question now is why???

Comment: @Daniel I gather you've already tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/9875701/116509 ? (You would need to update to a newer version of CXF)

Comment: Oh Wow! I totally forgot about this. I implemented this and sure enough the generated SQLService class has `"classpath:/net/rorg/rservice/sql/SQLServiceSoap.wsdl"` in it now (although I'm still using CXF 2.2.8). But the problem persists, because the client still attempts to connect to `http://localhost:8080/rservice/services/SQLServiceSoap`, which means the `config.xml` is nowhere to be injected (although it loads fine by the program). This may seem like an application-specific issue, but I couldn't find any place in the code where this substitution should occur. Ideas?

Comment: Are you calling `provider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, target)` with the correct run-time URL? Can you update question with the WSDL's `wsdl:service/wsdl:port/soap:address` (which I guess is set to `http://localhost:8080/rservice/services/SQLServiceSoap`)

Comment: Indeed, the `...getRequestContext()...` is what was missing. Turns out the wsdl2java wasn't generating that code and some "hidden trick" in the build environment copied "pre-manually-tweaked" version of that `SQLService.java` file. All is well now (work with CXF 2.2.8 but **not** with CXF 2.5.2 for some reason). Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel phew! Glad you got it working. And boo to confusing build tricks!